# Why does this while loop work with "and" operator and not with "or"?

Tags: java, boolean-operations

"||" does not work and gives an error message in the while loop. "&&" does and that's what I need, but I'm curious why it only works that way.

This is for a homework project for school. && works perfectly fine and gives no error message. I've also tried bracketing the individual expressions and switching them around, none of which worked.

```
//Below is line 29 in main calling the function
accCount = readAccts(acctNum, balance, MAX_NUM, inputfile);

//actual function attempting to read in data to an array
public static int readAccts(int[] acctNum, double[] balance,
            int MaxAccts, Scanner inputfile)
{
    int accCount = 0;

    //loop inputs account number and balance into array
    while(inputfile.hasNext() || accCount <= 50) {
                    //Line below is line 67 mentioned in error message
        acctNum[accCount] = inputfile.nextInt();
        balance[accCount] = inputfile.nextDouble();
        accCount++;
}
```

I get a compilation error message when using "||":

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at bankAccount.readAccts(bankAccount.java:67)
    at bankAccount.main(bankAccount.java:29)
```

Comment: Think about what your code does. If I have more input **or** the `accCount` is less than (or equal to) 50... ignore not having more input and get the input that isn't there. Make sense?

Comment: It's also not a compilation error, but an exception occuring at runtime of the program. Knowing this difference might help finding solutions for other problems in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The || operator is the or operator. When your code checks the condition `(inputfile.hasNext() || accCount <= 50)` if either `inputfile.hasNext()` or `accCount<=50` is true, then the loop will execute. So that means, even if there is nothing left to read in the file, if your `accCount` is less than or equal to 50, then the code will run and then throw an error when it tries to read a non existing line.

Answer (score 2):

Your while loop checks for two conditions: `input.hasNext()` and `accCount <= 50`. If you look at the stack trace, not only is the exception thrown from line 67 of your code, but also the exception is coming from the Scanner class itself.

Looking at [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), we can tell that a NoSuchElementException is thrown when input is exhausted. This tells me that something's up with your usage of the Scanner class. Turns out with the '||' or operator, when at least ONE of `input.hasNext()` or `accCount <= 50` is true, the loop advances — hence when there is no more input BUT `accCount <= 50`, you will then attempt to read the next int on line 67 and the Scanner will throw an exception, like it is doing now. Using `&&` avoids that because now `input.hasNext()` and `accCount <= 50` both have to be true — that is, there has to be valid upcoming input AND a valid account number. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

&& : it will check, if both the conditions are satisfied then only that block will execute.

|| : it will check 1st condition, if satisfied then will execute the block.
     if 1st condition fails, it will check 2nd condition.

- If you see the error, its at line no. 67 i.e "at
  java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)".
- So this simply means in your conditions, 1st conditions got failed
  and 2nd got satisfied because of which your block got executed. And since your Scanner was not having next element, if got failed to call nextInt() method as well.